# A family of polynomials for the Taylor expansion of the Lambert-w function

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, recurrence-relations, taylor-expansion, lambert-w

This is an attempt to derive the Taylor expansion at $0$ of the *Lambert $w$ function* (the branch containing the origin of the solution $w$ to the functional equation  $w(x)e^{w(x)}=x$) without resorting to *Lagrange inversion formula*, nor complex analysis.

Let the superscript $^{(n)}$, (superscript $^{'}$) denote the $n$-th derivative with respect to $x$ (to $w$ respectively) . It is easy to see that \begin{align*} w^{(1)}=\frac{w}{x}\frac{1}{w+1} .\end{align*}
Then by iterating the derivation process we obtain
\begin{align*} &w^{(2)}=-\frac{w^2}{x^2}\frac{w+2}{(w+1)^3} \\
&w^{(3)}=\frac{w^3}{x^3}\frac{2w^2+8w+9}{(w+1)^5}\\
&\qquad\qquad.....
\end{align*}
Now we start an induction process and we suppose that there is some polynomial $P_n$ such that
\begin{align*} &w^{(n)}=-\frac{(-w)^n}{x^n(w+1)^{2n-1}}P_n(w) 
\end{align*}
After some algebra we see that these polynomials must obey the following recursion:

> \begin{align*} P_{1}(w)&=1\\P_{n+1}(w)&=\big(n(w +3)-1\big)P_n(w)-(w+1)P_n^{'}(w). \end{align*}
>
> What is the name of these polynomials?
>
> How can it be shown that
> $P_n(0)=n^{n-1}$?

First instances:
\begin{align*}
P_1(w)&= \color{red}{1}\\
P_2(w)&=w+\color{red}{2}\\
P_3(w)&=2w^2+8w+\color{red}{9}\\
P_4(w)&=6w^3+36w^2+79w+\color{red}{64}\\
P_5(w)&=24w^4+192w^3+622w^2+974w+\color{red}{625}\\
\end{align*}

Or consider the triangle of numbers $a_{n,k}$ obtained recursively, such that the entries in line $n$ are computed with three consecutive entries from line $n-1$ by
$$ a_{n,k}=n a_{n-1,k-1}+(3n-(k+1))a_{n-1,k}-(k+1)a_{n-1,k+1}$$
with initial conditions $ a_{n,-1}= 0$ , $ a_{0,0}= 1$ and $ a_{0,k}= 0$ for $k>0$.

This makes it clear that $a_{n,n}=n!$, but how could we obtained the closed form $a_{n,0}=(n+1)^n$ ?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A042977 "Triangle $T(n,k)$ read by rows: coefficients of a polynomial sequence occurring when calculating the n-th derivative of Lambert function $W$."

Comment: These polynomials also appear as factors of the expressions in Example 4.3 of Kruchinin, V., "Derivation of Bell Polynomials of the Second Kind" https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5065

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer does not fully address the question of how to compute an explicit formula from the recursion relation (though it indicates a reference which contains a starting point), and so is not a proper answer, but it is too long for a comment, and I expect it might still be useful.

It follows from a comment by Vladimir Kruchinin in OEIS [A042977](http://oeis.org/A042977), "Triangle $T(n,k)$ read by rows: coefficients of a polynomial sequence occurring when calculating the $n$th derivative of Lambert function $W$" that $$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{P_n(w) = \sum_{m = 0}^n \left[ \sum_{j=0}^m {2 n + 1 \choose m - j} \sum_{k=0}^j (-1)^k \frac{(n+k+1)^{n+j}}{(j-k)! k!} \right] w^m}} .$$ See under the heading $\texttt{FORMULA}$, and NB that the expression in this answer differs from the one in OEIS entry by a factor of $(-1)^n$ to account for the formulation in the question. This expression can be deduced from Example 4.3 in Kruchinin's preprint ["Derivation of Bell Polynomials of the Second Kind"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5065).

In particular, to compute the constant term of $P_n(w)$, we can evaluate the inner sum for $j = 0$. Both summations have only a single term, and it simplifies to the conjectured formula, $$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{P_n(0) = (n + 1)^n}} .$$

Comment: This is very relevant and useful, and since I requested for reference, I accept it as an answer; but I agree that it is not entirely satisfactory: the formula for $P_n(w)$ was obtained by making use of the Lambert w function. Given the recursion only, without any other contextual info,  would there be a proof that does not make use of Lambert w ?

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer useful! I don't know any general methods for solving recursion formulas of the form of yours. You might even formulate a new question asking just about methods for solving the recursion. (If you do this, I suggest you link to this question for context.)